# Record sound from mic to file with sound meter in Java

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I am working on trying to record to file from a mic while sampling the audioInputStream for a sound meter. I cannot figure how to save the stream/sample to a file WHILE buffering a sample for metering. Here's some code fragments:

```
    format = new AudioFormat(11025, 16, 1, true, true);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    TargetDataLine line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
    line.open(format);
    line.start();   // start capturing
    in = new AudioInputStream(line);
```

I then start a thread to capture samples:

```
                int bytesRead = in.read(buffer, readPoint, buffer.length - readPoint);
                if (bytesRead == -1) {
                    notYetEOF = false;
                    break;
                }

                int leftover = bytesRead % frameSize;
                calculateRMSLevel(buffer, readPoint, leftover);
                ...
```

Here's where I'm stuck. I know I can't just use:

```
                AudioSystem.write(in, fileType, file);
```

because it will of course capture to file but this never comes back because the mic stream isn't shutting down. I've tried various ways of trying to change the byte[] data into an AudioInputStream with no success.

So, how can I capture data for sampling while synchronously (or better asynchronously) saving to a wav file input from a mic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to simply dump the raw audio data to a `tempFile` and once you are done recording, convert it to wave like this:

```
final AudioInputStream in = new AudioInputStream(
        new FileInputStream(tempFile),
        format,
        tempFile.length()/format.getFrameSize()
);
AudioSystem.write(in, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, file);
in.close();
```

The [wave format](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/audioformats/wave/wave.html) stipulates certain size info in its chunks that really can only be written *after* all data has arrived. That makes writing continuously from a stream a little hard. It simply wasn't meant to do that.